# Pashley serial number 43742?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Hi I have just purchased a second hand Pashley, the serial number appears to be 43742, however, it is difficult to see.  Can anyone tell me if this is a Roadster or a Princess please and would anyone have an idea of the date of the bike. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you checked their web site?

Comment: Note that a Roadster has a diamond "boy's" frame, while a Princess has a "girl's" frame.  https://www.pashley.co.uk/bikes/bicycles.php

Comment: From the web site:  *Every Pashley cycle has its own unique frame and serial numbers. They can be found on the cycle frame: the frame number is either stamped into a plate that forms the mount for the rear hub-brake arm on the left chainstay (the non-drive side - see 2), or under the bottom bracket (where the pedal crank-shaft is held - see 1); the serial number can be found on the security label affixed low down on the seat tube (the security label also displays the barcode unique to your cycle, plus a Union Jack).*

Comment: Your better option could be to contact Pashley directly.  https://www.pashley.co.uk/contact-form.php